# Can we get text scaling and monitor properties with WMI?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

It is possible to use WMI to detect things like:

- Text scaling
- Screen resolutions
- Multiple Monitor configuration/layout

?

I see `Win32_DesktopMonitor` but it doesn't seem to give me any of this info.

Comment: **Text scaling**: stored in a user-mode reg key, so WMI is not a great option. **Screen resolutions**: `Get-CimInstance CIM_VideoController | Select Name,Current*`. **Monitor layout**: The only decent way to get this is with Forms api, like `[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens`. I don't think it can be grabbed via WMI. It could help if you add more details about your environment/goal

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I have been using WMI in my Win32 app for displaying system info. It occurred to me that I don't have this screen data.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I am now using `Win32_VideoController` for some of the screen data. Although I do have 2 identical monitors connected to my PC and it only lists just the one. Where in the registry do you get the text scaling property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Text Scaling:** Stored in these two user registry values:

```
# AllUsers setting, which shows as (default)
(Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics").AppliedDPI
# User's current scaling settings for each monitor
(Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings\*").DpiValue

# AppliedDPI shows the "Default" scaling setting on a system level like:
96  : 100% 
120 : 125% 
144 : 150% 
192 : 200%  # (my default)
 
# DpiValue shows how many steps up or down *from Default* the current user's scaling setting is. 
# For example on my machine:
DpiValue : 2           # +2 = 250%
DpiValue : 0           # +0 = 200% (default)
DpiValue : 4294967294  # -1 = 150%
DpiValue : 4294967292  # -3 = 100%
```

**Monitor layout:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
```

**Screen resolutions:** Use the `AllScreens` enum above, or one of these:

```sh
Get-CimInstance Win32_DesktopMonitor | select Name,Screen*
Get-CimInstance CIM_VideoController  | Select Name,Current*
```

Comment: FYI, on my development PC that has 2 monitors I get this result `Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings' because it does not exist.`. But the `AppliedDPI` key worked.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle did you include the asterisk in the path? It looks like that key will not exist if you're currently using the default/all-users scaling value.

Comment: That will explain it. I am using the default/all-users scaling value, so the key doesn't exist. 